# MongoDB select best matched document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6347e5aa0c009a37b81da700"),
    "testField1" : "1000",
    "testField2" : "2000",
    "testField3" : NumberInt(1)
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6347e5890c009a37b81da701"),
    "testField2" : 2000,
    "testField3" : NumberInt(2)
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6347e5960c009a37b81da702"),
    "testField3" : NumberInt(3)
}]
```

I need to retrieve documents in the below precedence.

1. if testField1 and testField2 exist and match their values, the query should return that document.
2. Otherwise, if testField2 exists and matches its value, the query should return that document,
3. Otherwise it should return the last document, where testField1 & testField2 do not exist.

I tried the below query, but it returns all the documents.

```
db.getCollection("TEST_COLLECTION").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $and: {"testField1": "1000", "testField2": "2000"}
                    },
                    then: {
                        $and: {"testField1": "1000", "testField2": "2000"}
                    },
                    else : {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {
                                $and: {"testField1": null, "testField2": "2000"}
                            },
                            then: {
                                $and: {"testField1": null, "testField2": "2000"}
                            },
                            else : {
                                $and: {"testField1": null, "testField2": null}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Is `testField2` supposed to contain a string or a number? Will you always only be returning a single document, or is it possible for (eg) multiple documents to match the first condition (having appropriate `testField1` and `testField2` values) and should all be retrieved by the query?

Comment: @user20042973 I need to return only one document. testField1 & testField2 are string fields.
Only one document exists for one condition.

Comment: How are the 3 documents "grouped" / "linked" together? If there is another group of 3 documents, how can I distinguish them from the first group? Other than that, is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AsfIcVVDISG) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely still some open questions from the comments. @ray has an interesting approach linked in there that uses `$setWindowFields` which may be appropriate depending on exactly what you're looking for.

I took a different approach (and perhaps interpretation) and built out the following aggregation that uses `$unionWith`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      testField1: "1000",
      testField2: "2000"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      sortOrder: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            testField2: "2000"
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            sortOrder: 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            testField1: {
              $exists: false
            },
            testField2: {
              $exists: false
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            sortOrder: 3
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortOrder: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$unset": "sortOrder"
  }
])
```

Basically the aggregation will internally issue three queries, one corresponding with each of three precedence conditions. Similar to @ray's solution, it creates a field to sort on (`sortOrder` in mine) since the ordering of `$unionWith` is unspecified otherwise per the documentation. After the `$sort` we can `$limit` to a single result and `$unset` the temporary sorting field prior to returning the result to the client. Depending on the version you are running, you could consider adding a couple of inline `$limit`s for each of the subpipelines to reduce the amount of work being done. Along with appropriate indexes (perhaps just `{ testField2: 1, testField: 1 }`), this operation should be reasonably efficient.

[Here is the playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CXzpxZpuJq9).

Answer (score 0):

If there are several groups and you need to return the wanted document per group, I would go with @ray's answer. If there is only one group (as implies on your comment, and on @user20042973's nice answer), I would like to point another obvious option:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$facet: {
      op1: [{$match: {testField1: "1000", testField2: "2000"}}],
      op2: [{$match: {testField1: null, testField2: "2000"}}],
      op3: [{$match: {testField1: null, testField2: null}},
            {$sort: {timestamp: -1}}, {$limit: 1}]
  }},
  {$project: {res: {$ifNull: [{$first: "$op1"}, {$first: "$op2"}, {$first: "$op3"}]}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WgeWhSchasw)

Comment: This is definitely an option, and generally a great way to get started. The main downside to it is performance. At the time of writing, this operation is not going to be able to take advantage of any indexes and is going to scan the collection instead.